# Circuit Breaker implementation on function binding process/consume with spring cloud stream kafka

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-retry, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, circuit-breaker

[Here is my sample process and consume bean which I have set in function binding in application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNgu6.png)

I would like to add a circuit breaker to these functions but it won't work since these beans are just being read during project build. Goal is: I would like my circuit breaker to capture all exceptions that will be encountered during the stream before I get the message from kafka topic. sample exceptions(when kafka is down, deserialization) I would like to capture all of them in circuit breaker so I can pause/start kafka when circuit is open.

Btw, I have already implemented it on my service layer the part where business logic will occur. But that is only limited to the exceptions on my service and won't be able to capture all the exceptions in the stream.

The circuit breaker I'm using and needed to use is from spring.retry.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, are you able to solve this.

Comment: @APK, unfortunately no. It was really hard for us to put a circuit breaker in these functions as a whole. What we did right now is we just put a retryable for some API calls that we would like to cover. So whenever there is any unexpected exception that happen in the thread, kafka will shutdown and restart the pods in openshift.